# WinForms TabControl - Add New Tab Button (+)

Tags: c#, winforms, button, tabs, tabcontrol

How can I add a `+` button to the `TabControl` in a Windows Forms Application. Here is an answer for [WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468866/wpf-tabcontrol-add-new-tab-button). But I want it in WinForms application?

Answer (score 11):

You can add a new tab to the end of tabs of control and set it's text to `+` and then:

- Check if the user clicked on the last tab, then insert a new tab before it.
- You should prevent selection of the last tab.
- You should adjust the width of tabs and let the last tab have smaller width.

Then you will have a tab control like below. To have larger tab buttons, I have applied a padding to the control.

[image: Tab Control Add Button]

**Hanlde Click on Last Tab**

You can handle `MouseDown` or `MouseClick` event and check if the last tab rectangle contains the mouse clicked point, then insert a tab before the last tab:

```
private void tabControl1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var lastIndex = this.tabControl1.TabCount - 1;
    if (this.tabControl1.GetTabRect(lastIndex).Contains(e.Location))
    {
        this.tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(lastIndex, "New Tab");
        this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = lastIndex;
    }
}
```

**Prevent Selectin of Last Tab**

To prevent selection of last tab, you can handle `Selecting` event of control and check if the selecting tab is the last tab, cancel the event:

```
private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.TabPageIndex == this.tabControl1.TabCount - 1)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

**Adjust Width of Tabs**

To adjust tab width and let the last tab have smaller width, you can hanlde `HandleCreated` event and send a [`TCM_SETMINTABWIDTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tcm-setmintabwidth?WT.mc_id=5003235) to the control and specify the minimum size allowed for the tab width:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
private const int TCM_SETMINTABWIDTH = 0x1300 + 49;
private void tabControl1_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendMessage(this.tabControl1.Handle, TCM_SETMINTABWIDTH, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)16);
}
```

**Note**

- You can simply encapsulate the logic in a derived `TabContol` and make a custom tab control which supports adding tabs.
- **Close button**: Also you can simply make the control owner-draw and handle Painting of tabs to show a `+` icon and `X` icon on tabs. As an example you can see an implementation in this post: [TabControl with Close and Add Button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36900582/3110834).
- **Right to Left (RTL) support**: You can add support for RTL when using owner-draw tab. This post: [Close button for TabPages of Right To Left TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34508176/close-button-for-tabpages-of-right-to-left-tabcontrol-c-sharp) is a solution.

Answer (score 6):

I would add a new TabPage, then set the header to "+", set it's name to newTabPage and add an event for the TabControl's SelectedIndexChanged. Then you just check if

```
tabcontrol.SelectedTab == newTabPage
```

and if that is the case you can create a new TabPage, insert it into tabControl and set it as the SelectedTab like:

```
tabControl.TabPages.Insert(tabControl.TabPages.Count - 1, createdTabPage);
tabControl.SelectedTab = createdTabPage;
```

Comment: There is a little problem with this solution. '+' tab header width is too big. Plus sign is aligned by left side. It looks bad. How can i decrease tab header width?

Comment: I couldn't directly find a decent way to do this, but possibly the easiest way to make it look nice though is to use something like (Add Page) or some instruction which is a bit longer and fills the space.

Comment: To adjust tab width and let the last tab have smaller width, you can hanlde `HandleCreated` event and send a `TCM_SETMINTABWIDTH` to the control and specify the minimum size allowed for the tab width. Here I shared an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36959196/3110834) which adjusts the tab width.

Answer (score 0):

Create a tab with tag "+" , and use "tabControl1_Selecting" event, and the code this:

```
if(e.TabPageIndex==tabControl1.TabPages.Count-1)
    tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(tabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1,"tab"+e.TabPageIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some improvements according to @Reza Aghaei

1. Create a new form and name it formTab(set the form boarder style to none).
2. Set the controls of formTab (this will be the controls set in the new tab).
3. go back to the tabcontrol and add a new tab, name it "+"(make sure that this **tab is the end of tabcontrol**).

your form should look some what like these:
[form1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVcPZ.png)
[formTab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8EdD.png)

now type in these codes:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage tab = tabControl1.TabPages[0];
        var newTab = new formTab();
        newTab.TopLevel = false;
        newTab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        newTab.Show();
        newTab.Visible = true;
        tab.Controls.Add(newTab);
    }


private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabAdd = tabControl1.TabCount - 1;

        if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == tabAdd)
        {
            //create a new tabpage
            var t = new TabPage();

            //create a new formTab with webControl in it
            var newTab = new formTab();

            //show the new formTab
            newTab.Show();
            newTab.TopLevel = false;
            newTab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            newTab.Visible = true;

            //add formTab as new control in the tabpage just created
            t.Controls.Add(newTab);

            //insert the new created tab into tab control and before tabLoc
            tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(tabAdd, t);

            //select the new created tab
            var newCreatedTab = tabControl1.TabCount - 2;
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = newCreatedTab;
        }
    }
```

hope it helps!