# How can I write a generic method to add any form to a tab control and set properties on those forms?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, generics

I am trying to write a generic method which would allow me to add a form as the contents of a Tab on a tab control, however I am only able to figure out how to add it when specifying the exact form I wish to add.

Suppose I have three forms `Form1`, `Form2`, and `Form3` where `Form1` contains the tab control `tabControl1`, and `Form2` inherits `Form`, where `Form3` inherits `MetroForm`. Following is the method I am currently using :

```
private void AddFormAsTab() {
    Form3 f = new Form3()
    {
        TopLevel = false,
        ShowInTaskbar = false,
        ControlBox = false,
        SizeGripStyle = SizeGripStyle.Hide,
        Visible = false,
        Text = string.Empty,
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        MinimizeBox = false,
        MaximizeBox = false,
        ShadowType = MetroFormShadowType.None,
        Movable = false
    };

    TabPage tab = new TabPage();
    tab.Controls.Add( f );
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add( tab );
    f.Visible = true;
}
```

What I would like to do, is modify this method so that `AddFormAsTab()` accepts any form type and sets the properties as necessary (to ensure they are set as I am lazy and do not wish to change all those properties on every form I design perpetually when recycling this component)

I have seen this done in other controls such as Telerik, and DevExpress where the control accepts a generic and modifies it to 'fit' the purpose. In my case, I am changing the properties of the form so that it fills the tabpage, has no border, title bar, etc.

I have considered using `(typeof(T))obj` type code, but this generates pre-compile errors where those properties do not exist in `obj` which prevent it from being built, even though in theory, this should work.

I have also tried stuff like `Form f = new Form1()`, however this doesn't work as `Form` is not the same type as `Form1` which happens to inherit `Form`.

What can I do to make this happen, to allow any form to be set without hardcoding those specific forms classes into the `AddFormAsTab()` method, but still delegate responsibility to set the required properties to that method ?

Ideally, something like :

```
private void AddFormAsTab<T>(T obj) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either of these options:

```
public void AddFormAsTab<T>() where T : Form, new()
{
    var f = new T();
    f.TopLevel = false;
    //...
}
```

Usage:

```
AddFormAsTab<Form1>();
```

Or

```
public void AddFormAsTab(Form f)
{
    f.TopLevel = false;
    //...
}
```

Usage:

```
AddFormAsTab(new Form1());
```

Comment: Looks good.  I can't test this just yet as I am uninstalling VS2013 (tested VS2015 long enough to be ready to ditch 2k13) so while that is uninstalling I can't play so much.  Can this form of method be overloaded ?  Like `Form3` in my example is of the `MetroForm` base class.  So could I do two of these methods of the same name (`AddFormAsTab<T>`) just one says `where T : MetroForm, new()` and the other `where T : Form, new()`

Comment: Also, the problem with the `Form f` is it is not the same type as `Form1`, so Likely will use the first method as it looks like it takes into account the actual form as well as the inherited type instead of just assuming it is generic `Form`  :) -- I have had problems with `Form f = new Form1()` code in the past.

Comment: *1)* You can simply use this signature: `public void AddFormAsTab<T>() where T : MetroForm, new()` but you can not both `where T : MetroForm` and `where T : Form` and you don't need, because `MetroForm` derives from `Form` so I believe `here T : Form` is enough.

Comment: *2)* `public void AddFormAsTab(Form f) Is OK`, because both `Form1` and `Form2` are `Form` and based on [Polymorphism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx) rules you can pass any class which derived from `Form` to the method. In your case you may prefer public void `AddFormAsTab(MetroForm f)` overload, while I think `public void AddFormAsTab(Form f)` is enough.

Comment: Using the `T` method, could you show me how I would dispose of the form when the tab is disposed safely please ?  I was considering inline event handler but that would make it so I am unable to unsubscribe from those events (memory leak).

Comment: Since you added forms as child controls and they are present in `Controls` collection of your tabpages,  You don't need to dispose forms manually. But if you created a method to remove a tab page from `TabPages` collection, you need to `Close` your form.

Comment: A little bit confused.  I understand if I close the main form containing the tab control, all objects get their `Dispose()` method called, however when a Tab is removed (aka, tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(1)` am I not required to call `Dispose()` on the form or objects that were on that tab, and if so, is it as simple as `var tp = ...TabPages[1]; foreach(var control in tp.Controls { control.Dispose(); }  .... TabPages[1].Dispose();`  ?

Comment: *if I close the main form containing the tab control, all objects get their Dispose() method called* →Yes, it works this way. So you don't need to dispose child controls manually. But when you want to remove tab, first kepp a reference to the tab, then remove it, then cast the first control of tab to `Form` and call it's `Close` method.

Comment: By the way, since you are creating a Tabbed UI, you may find this post useful [TabControl with Close and Add Button](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36900582/3110834). But pay attention, you should handle closing the form yourself.