# C# tabcontrol remove drawing string from specific tab page

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabs

In winforms tabcontrols i have default tab with name `start`. This tab is always opened and cant be closed! Another tabs has `X` draw string for closing tab.

In my case all tabas including `Start` tab has `X` drawstring for closing.

I want to remove `X` just on `Start` tab.

Here is my code

```
private void mainTabControl_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    //This code will render a "x" mark at the end of the Tab caption. 
    e.Graphics.DrawString("x", e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Right - CLOSE_AREA, e.Bounds.Top + 4);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(this.mainTabControl.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left + LEADING_SPACE, e.Bounds.Top + 4);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    mainTabControl.Padding = new Point(21, 3);
}
```

[image]

Comment: "If sender is start tab, don't add an x"

Comment: Show example in code

Comment: `if (sender is start tab) return;` - it's up to you to decide how to tell, you could for example cast it back to the tab type and check the name. or that it's the first, or …

Comment: I can slowe this with `if (e.Index == 0)  drawString = "" else { drawString = "x"` Its working now

Comment: Take a look at this post [TabControl with Close and Add Button](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36900582/3110834). The same way that `x` is not drawn for last tab and instead `+` is drawn, you can check only if `e.Index` is greater than 0, then draw close icon. Also don't forget to include this criteria also in `MouseDown` or `MouseClick` event to prevent closing the first tab.

Comment: Yes but his answer not help me.

Comment: No problem,but those tab pages are more beautiful and the code is more clean and more structured.