# Winforms - How to get tabs/tools strip to look like SSMS

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, tabs, ssms

Windows Form applications have an out-the-box tab control but it looks basic.

Are there any other controls (including 3rd party) that have a control like the one found in SSMS (see below image)?

Is this control custom rendered? If so, what control would you inherit from to create something like this?

[image: SSMS UI]

Comment: https://github.com/dockpanelsuite

Comment: Its written using WPF rather than Windows Forms btw.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you! That is what I was looking for.

Comment: If you don't need docking and floating windows, consider using an owner drawn `TabControl`. You may find this post useful: [TabControl with Close and Add Button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36900582/3110834)