# How to properly dock to the right a form to a MDI in a Windows Form application?

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, mdi

I am adding to a MDI a side bar form (not a child) and docking it to the right.
The top of the side bar appears to overlapping the toolbar. When doing a manual resizing (by dragging), the side bar is "magically" looks fine.

**Before resizing:**

[image]

**After Resizing:**

[image]

```
public partial class MDI : Form
{
    private void InitGenealogicalTree()
    {
        var form = new GenealogicalTreeForm();            
        form.TopLevel = false;
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        form.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
        this.Controls.Add(form);
    }
}
```

Note: The ToolStrip was added in design mode.

How can I properly add the side bar form without having it overlapping the toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A side-bar windows should not be movable and should not be resizeable and should not be maximize-able, so:

- Set `FormBorderStyle` to `FixedToolWindow`.
- Override `WndProc` of the side-bar window `WndProc` to prevent move and prevent maximize:

  ```
  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
  {
      const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
      const int SC_MOVE = 0xf010;
      const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xf030;
      if (m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
      {
          int command = m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
          if (command == SC_MOVE || command == SC_MAXIMIZE)
              return;
      }
      base.WndProc(ref m);
  }
  ```
- Also when adding the side-bar, bring it to front. It means first toolbar should be docked, then the side-bar windows will be docked in the remaining area:

  ```
  this.Controls.Add(sideBar);
  sideBar.BringToFront();
  ```

Comment: Wow, thank you for open mind. I didn't though how I will prevent from moving it. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome :) For such multi-window UI, I prefer to not use MDI. Instead, create a multi-tab UI. Each child form will be added as borderless child in a new Tab, you can show [close button on tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36900582/3110834). The sidebar is also a form which is hosted in a docked panel to the right. You can also use a splitter between the side panel and the tabcontrol to allow resizing the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a panel in desigenermode where you want to have your sidepanel and display the sidepanel in the panel.

---

The following codes lets you display the side bar form in the panel:

```
var form = new GenealogicalTreeForm();            
form.TopLevel = false;
panel.Controls.Add(form);
form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.Controls.Add(form);
form.Show();
```