# How do I get the refreshed list of TabPages after event ControlRemoved event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` to which the user can add/remove `TabPage`s using two user buttons. To get a clear idea, the GUI looks like this:

[image]

If the user clicks on the "Plus" icon (the `Parent` being the main form which is also the `Parent` of the `TabControl` itself), a new `TabPage` containing a custom user control gets added:

```
TabPage indicator = new TabPage();
indicator.Controls.Add(new IndicatorTab(this.conditionsTab, this.limitsTab) { Dock = DockStyle.Fill});
indicatorsTab.TabPages.Add(indicator);
```

If the user clicks on the "Remove" button inside the User Control, the following occurs:

```
Parent.Dispose();
```

I have added an `ControlEventHandler` to this `TabControl` for the events `ControlAdded` and `ControlRemoved`, in which I run this loop:

```
foreach (TabPage indicator in indicatorsTab.TabPages)
{
    //stuff
}
```

My problem is the following:

- When the `ControlAdded` event is triggered, I find in `indicatorsTab.TabPages` all the `TabPage` *including the one just added* - **EXPECTED TO ME**
- When the `ControlRemoved` event is triggered, I find in `indicatorsTab.TabPages` all the `TabPage` *including the one just removed* - **UNEXPECTED TO ME**

I wouldn't expect the removed tab to be in `indicatorsTab.TabPages` after the `ControlRemoved` was triggered.
So I have a couple of questions:

1. Am I being wrong in my logic? Is it expected the removed `TabPage`to be still in the collection right after the event is triggered?
2. How can I get the refreshed list of `TabPage`s after the removal event?
3. Don't know why but I get the feeling this diverging behavior has something to see with the fact that the `ControlAdded` event is triggered by a "brother" control (child of the same `Parent` than the `TabControl`), while the `ControlRemoved` is triggered by a child of the `TabControl` itself... if so, can anyone please explain?

Comment: The `TabPages` collection has not been updated, yet. It will be, after the `ControlRemoved` event. You could use the `indicatorsTab.Controls` collection in the loop: `foreach (TabPage indicator in indicatorsTab.Controls) (...)`. Or check the `e.Control` object (the Control just removed) and skip it in the loop (using its `Name`, maybe, to identify it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delay the eventhandler execution until after the remove is processed:

```
private void tabControl1_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(tabControl1.TabCount.ToString());
    }));
}
```

It shows the expected result.

**Note:** `TabControl` has its own `ControlsCollection` class and in its [`Remove`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabControl.cs,6cba8857b84046b6) method, it first removes the `TabPage` control from `Controls` collection and raises `ControlRemoved`, then removes the `TabPage` from `TabPages` collection. So as a result, in the `ControlRemoved` event, the `TabPage` still exists in `TabPages` collection, but not in `Controls` collection.

Comment: Thank you, will try this later and accept the answer if it works!

Comment: It works exactly the way I wanted it, thank you very much! Still, it would be interesting to know why the `ControlAdded` takes the new `TabPage` into account while the `ControlRemoved` doesn't, but that's of secondary importance now :)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ You're welcome. Updated the answer to contain some information about how removing tab pages works in tab control. Take a look at source code of [`Remove`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabControl.cs,6cba8857b84046b6) method for better understanding.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ  If you take a look at the source code, you'll clearly see that the [Add method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabControl.cs,2733) first adds the `TabPage` to the collection, then calls `base.Add(tabPage)`. The opposite in the `Remove` method.

Comment: @Jimi interesting catch, if you write it as an answer I will at least upvote it as it responds to one of my "lower priority" questions :)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ As an off-topic note, regarding to the UI that I see in your question, you may be interested to a [TabControl with Close and Add Button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36900582/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei oh, that's a pity, I've already implemented everything! But I've added your approach to my favorites for the next time I'll have to do it!