# Close button on Tab pages in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, tabcontrol, ownerdrawn

I am trying to add a close button on the tab pages of TabControl and
change the color of the close button from light gray to black when
mouse hovers over it. However, the color never changes.

The DrawEventArgsCustom class is created to indicate that the mouse is
hovering over the close button. When it's true, the statement to
change the color is executed but color never changes.

```cs
private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        Rectangle r = e.Bounds;
        r = this.tabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index);
        r.Offset(2, 2);
        Brush TitleBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        Brush CloseBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray);
        Brush CloseBrushSelected = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        Font f = this.Font;
        string title = this.tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text;

        e.Graphics.DrawString(title, f, TitleBrush, new PointF(r.X, r.Y));
        if (e is DrawEventArgsCustom)
        {
            if (((DrawEventArgsCustom)e) != null && ((DrawEventArgsCustom)e).HoverTrue == true)
                e.Graphics.DrawString("x", f, CloseBrushSelected, new PointF
             (r.X + (this.tabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index).Width - _imageLocation.X), _imageLocation.Y));
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawString("x", f, CloseBrush, new PointF
              (r.X + (this.tabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index).Width - _imageLocation.X), _imageLocation.Y));


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

private void tabControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle mouseRect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 1, 1);
    Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics();
    for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabCount; i++)
    {
        if (tabControl1.GetTabRect(i).IntersectsWith(mouseRect))
        {

            tabControl1_DrawItem(this, new DrawEventArgsCustom(hoverTrue: true, graphics, this.Font, mouseRect, i, DrawItemState.Focus));

        }
    }
}

class DrawEventArgsCustom : DrawItemEventArgs
{


    public DrawEventArgsCustom(bool hoverTrue, Graphics graphics, Font font, Rectangle rect, int index, DrawItemState drawItemState)
        : base(graphics, font, rect, index, drawItemState)
    {
        this.HoverTrue = hoverTrue;
        this.Graph = graphics;
        this.Fnt = font;
        this.Rect = rect;
        this.ind = index;
        this.drawItemSt = drawItemState;
    }


    public bool HoverTrue { get; private set; }
    public Graphics Graph { get; private set; }
    public Font Fnt { get; private set; }
    public Rectangle Rect { get; private set; }
    public int ind { get; private set; }
    public DrawItemState drawItemSt { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to create new `Graphics` objects like that, you should do all the drawings in the `DrawItem` event. For example in this context:

```cs
//a class level variable.
private int HoverIndex = -1;

private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;
    var tp = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];
    var rt = e.Bounds;
    var rx = new Rectangle(rt.Right - 20, (rt.Y + (rt.Height - 12)) / 2 + 1, 12, 12);

    if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) != DrawItemState.Selected)
    {
        rx.Offset(0, 2);
    }

    rt.Inflate(-rx.Width, 0);
    rt.Offset(-(rx.Width / 2), 0);

    using (Font f = new Font("Marlett", 8f))
    using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat()
    {
        Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
        LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
        Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter,
        FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoWrap,
    })
    {
        g.DrawString(tp.Text, tp.Font ?? Font, Brushes.Black, rt, sf);
        g.DrawString("r", f, HoverIndex == e.Index ? Brushes.Black : Brushes.LightGray, rx, sf);
    }
    tp.Tag = rx;
}
```

Note that, now the `Tag` property of each `TabPage` control holds a rectangle for the `x` button.

In the `MouseMove` event iterate through the `TabPages`, cast the `x` rectangle from the `Tag` property, check if the `x` rectangle contains the current `e.Location`, and call `Invalidate();` method of the `TabControl` to update the drawing:

```cs
private void tabControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabCount; i++)
    {
        var rx =(Rectangle)tabControl1.TabPages[i].Tag;

        if (rx.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            //To avoid the redundant calls. 
            if (HoverIndex != i)
            {
                HoverIndex = i;
                tabControl1.Invalidate();
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    //To avoid the redundant calls.
    if (HoverIndex != -1)
    {
        HoverIndex = -1;
        tabControl1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

In the `MouseLeave` event invalidate if necessary:

```cs
private void tabControl1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HoverIndex != -1)
    {
        HoverIndex = -1;
        tabControl1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

And to close/dispose a page, handle the `MouseUp` event:

```cs
private void tabControl1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabCount; i++)
    {
        var rx = (Rectangle)tabControl1.TabPages[i].Tag;

        if (rx.Contains(rx.Location)) //changed e.Location to rx.Location
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages[i].Dispose();
            return;
        }                                    
    }
}
```

> **Related Posts**
>
> <sup>[TabControl with Close and Add Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895089/tabcontrol-with-close-and-add-button/36900582#36900582)</sup>