# TabControl with an new tab button

Tags: wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I have the following TabControl:

```
<TabControl x:Name="Networks">
  <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
        <Button Content="X" cal:Message.Attach="CloseItem($dataContext)" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

As you can see it is bound to a ViewModel using Caliburn.Micro, but I think this is unrelevant.
How would I add a button on to this control on the right side to add new TabItems? I'm looking for simple solution. I've searched for this but I haven't found an easy implementation of this.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468866/wpf-tabcontrol-add-new-tab-button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the `ItemsSource` a [`CompositeCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx) with a [`CollectionContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectioncontainer.aspx) for the tabs at the beginning and one explicit `TabItem` at the end which can add a new item on click (a `+`-tab as in some browsers).

Comment: I've tried this, but the binding doesn't seem to work. I have a BindableCollection<T>, I've read that you can only bind freezable collections.

Comment: @errorcode007: There is no `DataContext` in a `CollectionContainer` and you cannot use `ElementName` or `RelativeSource` either ([see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446699/how-do-you-bind-a-collectioncontainer-to-a-collection-in-a-view-model)). You could of course create the collection in the VM and work with simple assignments.

Comment: @errorcode007: Also `IEditableCollectionView` is for just this use-case, see the duplicate linked to in the comment, there's a better solution than this.

Comment: What's the best way to handle `SelectedItem` using this solution?  I'm currently getting errors when I click on the new tab because it's trying to convert my explicit `TabItem` into the type the `ItemSource` of the `CompositeCollection` is bound to.

Comment: @NathanFriend: Not sure, maybe you can set some properties on the `TabItem` to make it un-selectable (disable parts/focusability, things like that). Alternatively you could bind to property of type `object` and create another properly typed property that returns `<raw property> as <yourtype>`, so that will just be `null` for the new item tab.

Comment: Thanks, @H.B.  I ended up specifying a converter that returned `null` when the binding attempted to convert the static item into the bound list's data type.