# Adding plus button in WPF tab control after the last tab item?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I would like to achieve the "new tab" functionality of web browsers in WPF. In essence, I want to display a button after the last tab item which upon pressed creates a new tab.

I have no idea where to even begin. Should this button be part of the tab control or be out of it?

Okay, I found an answer, a duplicate: [TabControl with Add New Tab Button (+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468866/wpf-tabcontrol-with-add-new-tab-button)

Comment: Asked before, multiple times.

Comment: Can you give me a link, at least not on the Related list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF TabControl with Add New Tab Button (+)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468866/wpf-tabcontrol-with-add-new-tab-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some links are

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20860/An-Extended-WPF-TabControl

http://fabtab.codeplex.com/